# AWS DynamoDB DynamoDbEnhancedClient Asynchronous?

Tags: amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk-2.x

Are the methods available in DynamoDbEnhancedClient asynchronous? In [this documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/introducing-enhanced-dynamodb-client-in-the-aws-sdk-for-java-v2/), it is mentioned that it is truly asynchronous and it returns CompletableFuture but the java docs mention it returns BatchGetResultPageIterable.

Does BatchGetResultPageIterable internally use the CompletableFuture or the methods batchGetItem etc of DynamoDbEnhancedClient are synchronous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In aws-java-sdk-2.x DynamoDbEnhancedClient is for synchronous calls and [DynamoDbEnhancedAsyncClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/DynamoDbEnhancedAsyncClient.html) is for running commands asynchronously.